# Saving ggmap object to a file which can be reused?

Tags: r, plot, save, gis, ggmap

Is it possible to save a ggmap to a local file?

Context: I need a high resolution map of a big region, which takes the `stamen` server quite a long time to get. I think it would be better, to get the map once, save it to a file and from then on, work on the local copy.

My code for getting the map is:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c(left = 8.7, bottom = 46.8, right = 9.7, top = 47.6), zoom = 14, maptype = c("toner"))
```

I know I can save it as an image for example with:

```
png(filename=name, width=1280, height=1280)
print(map)
dev.off()
```

But this doesn't help, because I want to use the map later on to plot different points and polygons on it, which is only possible if the map knows the 'lat' and 'lon' of every point on the picture.

So, is there a way to save the map in it's raw data form?

Comment: You can save your object `map` in a RData file: `save(map, file = "xy.RData")`. Then call it back: `load("xy.RData")`. Don't forget to load the library `ggmap`, in order to make R to recognize the class of `map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by [user3710546](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296701/r-saving-ggmap-to-file#comment46791701_29296701) save the ggmap object to a RData file with `save` function, and then, read it back with `load`. For example:

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map(location="California", zoom=6, maptype="terrain")

save(map, file = "my_map.RData")
load(file = "my_map.RData")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `write.table(map,file="filename")` to save it in a file.

Comment: Reading back the file written like this with `map2 <- read.table(file="filename")` I get an object of type `list` that cannot be plotted using `ggmap`.
Is there a way to read the file back in a way it remains a plottable object of type `ggmap`?

Comment: It's because some informations about the object are missing. You can try to save it with `dput(map,filename)`to save it and `dget(filename)`to download it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. `dput(map, "mapdata")` puts a file on disk, which is ok. When I try `dget("mapdata")` R is hanging for minutes and nothing happens. Any hints?

Comment: I tried with a zoom=2 and it worked. Maybe it's longer with a zoom = 14. Can you try with a smaller zoom to see if it is the problem ?

Comment: @Pascal 's idea with `save` and `load` works perfectly fine, so I will go for that solution.